# Amplify DataStore - update mutation complaining about missing fields that aren't missing

Tags: aws-amplify, datastore

I'm using AWS Amplify DataStore to update a model.
First, I create the model with some basic data, and that saves fine.
Then I update some fields.  Say, `first_name`, and then DataStore generates a mutation (below).  It returns an error:

DataStore - conflict trycatch Error: Field tenant is required is a WARN to the console, and the following is the payload returned. Note that `tenant` is not sent in the update, nbut is on the mutation.   Should it be an error?  Is this a DataStore bug, or mine? How can I bypass this problem?

```js
{
  "data": {
    "updatePerson": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "updatePerson"
      ],
      "data": {
        "id": "fd3d6333-3217-416b-8f89-2083826d97e3",
        "tenant": "2faa7d6a-0e81-442d-9714-0c6bf1ff1761",
        "owner": null,
        "username": null,
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        // ...
        "createdAt": "2023-04-19T15:55:59.998Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-04-19T15:55:59.998Z",
        "_version": 1,
        "_lastChangedAt": 1681919760022,
        "_deleted": null
      },
      "errorType": "ConflictUnhandled",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Conflict resolver rejects mutation."
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// Mutation
mutation operation($input: UpdatePersonInput!, $condition: ModelPersonConditionInput) {
  updatePerson(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
    id
    tenant  // this is the missing one
    owner
    username
    first_name
    last_name
    ...
    _version
    _lastChangedAt
    _deleted
  }
}
```

```js
// Variables  (note that tenant is missing.  This is what DataStore generated)
{
  "input": {
    "id": "fd3d6333-3217-416b-8f89-2083826d97e3",
    "first_name": "1"
  },
  "condition": null
}
```

I expect there not to be an error when the required field is present.